# WSDL web reference client and alter method to return soap string

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, client

First of all I am complete noob in WCF/WSDL area so please be patient with me

Okay, I have got a WSDL,XSD for complex message types, I generated a test client in C# console application. I added a web reference to WSDL got code generated in reference.cs.

I called methods available in reference.cs, fine works perfect. I added soap trace extension on methods in reference.cs to log soap requests/response, works fine.

In client I get WSDL complex type class object, where I see everything is returned fine for both sync and async calls.

Now this is what I want/trying to do, I want methods to return not deserialized class object but soap string, like they are received in stream and before deserialization.

How do I alter method to return soap string? It's not about accessing them(which I succceed to do) but to return directly from method.

Please point me in right direction else I have to go in implementing a soapclient, which I trying to avoid.

I appreciate any help. Let me know if I should clarify things.

Update:

Okay sir, this is what I did:

generated a class from WSDL using svcutil, then:

```
ServiceClient1 sc1 = new ServiceClient1();
TestResponseClass trc1 = sc1.method1("Testinput");
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TestResponseClass ),"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.local/Service1.wsdl");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
x.Serialize(stringWriter, trc1);
Console.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
```

this way I got xml response. more close to what I was willing to have, I'll try to convert it to soap response. I hope I am on right track now. Please correct if not. learning and learning fast...I guess

Comment: Why do you want a "SOAP Response"?

Comment: Thanks for reply.You put me on right track. It's a bit complicated to explain but in short, there will be another client connected to my client and they have wish for soap envelope but I am thinking again, I better settle on XML as above.Could you please check if above way of serializing to XML back is correct and efficient(although it does give me the correct XML).Thank you John.

Comment: How is this other client connected to yours? If over a network, then there is no problem. You _still_ don't need to play with XML.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up response. I figured it out that I don't need soap message for other client, only XML will do so serializing back to XML suffice. One last question, is that a correct way, I doubt because of double serialization/deserialization? Other client will be having a dll to make calls thorugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be getting confused a bit. Do not use Web References. This is the legacy ASMX technology which has been replaced by WCF and "Add Service Reference".

Do not use ASMX for new development.

---

I have seen your update, and you are, indeed, confused.

Your code has:

```
ServiceClient1 sc1 = new ServiceClient1();
TestResponseClass trc1 = sc1.method1("Testinput");
```

That's it. You're done. You have already sent a SOAP message to the service and have already received the response. There is no need to work with XML, at all.

Comment: Thanks,your answer highly appreciatee, okay I tried it with service reference too. Same thing, I want to alter my method code to return soap as is in string or stream (which I think is only exposed to SoapExtension). Is it okay or good way to again deserialize the response class object, back to soap, based on schema used in WSDL? it sounds strange to me as WCF already serialize it from stream and I want WCF to better not serialize it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should maybe give more detail, because this doesn't make much sense. You don't use SoapExtension with WCF. What do you mean by "return SOAP string"? You don't need or want to return a SOAP string in general.

Comment: Thanks again John, what I want is my soapdocument attribute method, to return me a soap xml string or stream, it's returning a complex type class object(generated from WSDL) at the moment(this is how it should be acutely).

Comment: This is where your confusion lies. You shouldn't be using `[SoapDocumentMethod]` at all. You shouldn't be writing ASMX services at all. Please see "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)" which shows how to create a service using the correct technology, and then shows how to consume it.

Comment: Thank you John for pointing me out,I'll follow your example and report tomorrow, If I get what I need. Thanks again.